# In Meteor, how to find which session variable triggers a template rerun

Tags: meteor

This is a general question about designing meteor applications or debugging meteor applications.

When I write meteor applications, I usually update session variable values to trigger re-runing a template helper function and/or re-rendering a template. So my application has quite a few different session variables.

Sometimes I find that the helper function gets re-run multiple times, but I can't think of any reason why it re-runs so many times. It must be some session variable gets updated and causes the re-run. Is there a way to figure out which session variable causes it?

The general question is: in a reactive design, when I see a template gets re-rendered, how to find why it gets re-rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Deps.autorun to quickly figure out which it is, If you're looking to debug its a quick a gritty way to do

Drop in the code like

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
   Session.get("something");
   console.log("Session something has changed");
});

Deps.autorun(function() {
   Meteor.user()
   console.log("Meteor user has changed");
});
```

You can place blocks of code like this on your client side to see which is changing. Each one will run once, initially, then after for each time the reactive variable inside it changes.

You would have to do this for each variable you use in your template and it would help you find out which is changing, each Deps.autorun block will run independently only when the variable inside it changes.

Comment: Yes. It tells me that one session variable is changed. But it doesn't tell me where it gets changed. Is there a way to figure out where it is changed? Thanks.

Comment: @Fei by where do you mean in code? You would have to use Chrome's webkit debugger, adding breakpoints to wherever you use something to change a reactive variable and then run your code. This is a good tutorial on it: https://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r421/trunk/tutorials/breapoints/index.html